# Display Gallery Images from Custom Post Type

Tags: gallery, images

I want to display all the images added as gallery in a post with prettyphoto class.

I am using this code.

```
    <?php
        /* The loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
                $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );

             /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
                foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src )
                {
                    ?>

                 <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo $src; ?>"  alt="Gallery image"  /></a>

                <?php
                }
            endif;
            endwhile;
    ?>
```

Its is displaying the photos but it is showing only thumbnail as src. I want to display Full Image.

How can i display full image instead of thumbnail ?

Comment: work on your acceptance rate, if somebody gives you an  answer which helps you to resolve your issue, then mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the foreach loop as follows,

```
 foreach( $gallery['ids'] as $attachment_id )
 {
       $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
       if( $image_attributes ) {

           $src = isset($image_attributes[0])? $image_attributes[0] : '';

            if(!empty($src)) {
                ?>

             <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo $src; ?>"  alt="Gallery image"  /></a>

            <?php
            }
       }
  }
```

You can specify required dimension, as second parameter for , 'wp_get_attachment_image_src()' function.

Answer (score 0):

TutsPlus did [a pretty straightforward article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-prettyphoto-with-post-images-in-your-themes/) on exactly this a while back. Perhaps you could give it a read and let us know if you run into any problems? This forum is good with problems. The basis of your question is more of a "point me at a tutorial" issue though. Done and done :)

You may need to refer to a [code snip like this](http://www.remicorson.com/tip-add-a-rel-attribute-to-wordpress-gallery-for-lightbox-use/) to get gallery integration though, once you've done the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Query the custom post type to display
$args = array('post_type' => 'CUSTOM POST TYPE');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
   // your gallery loop
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for [get_post_gallery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) and you'll see that the function is intended to return thumbnail image sources. The function also returns a string IDs of images. So you can split it into array, and run [wp_get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link) within the same loop (with a defined index to reference correct image file ID) to query for full image source.